# How do I add a variable's value to a picture in JES/ Jython?

Tags: python, image, variables, jython, jes

As per the topic, How do I add a variable's value to a picture?

I have an image I want to add a variable's value to, and prefferably a word before and/ or after.

The question's topic may be answerable from Jython/ Python knowledge as they sometimes work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
custom_text = "foo bar"

# addText(picture, xpos, ypos, text)
# add text "foo bar" to custom_picture, starting at (15, 50)
addText(custom_picture, 15, 50, custom_text)

# add text "kung-foo bar" to custom_picture2, starting at (40, 20)
addText(custom_picture2, 40, 20, "kung-" + custom_text)

new_custom_text = "kung-" + custom_text
# add text "kung-foo bar" to new_custom_picture, starting at (10, 30)
addText(new_custom_picture, 10, 30, new_custom_text)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I want.  Thankyou!  I'd upvote you but every time I ask a question lately my rep goes down, sorry!